# throw different exception when catch DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am using spring mvc, to handle excpetion i use global exception handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT, reason = "Data integrity violation")
    @ExceptionHandler({DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
    public @ResponseBody AdminResponse handleConflict(DataIntegrityViolationException ex,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

        AdminResponse error = new AdminResponse ();

        error.setStatus(Status.FAILURE);
        error.setErrorDescription(ex.getMessage());

        return error;
    }
```

Spring tack care of catching `DataIntegrityViolationException`, but i need to extend `DataIntegrityViolationException` at the same time i cannot force Spring to catch my custom exception.
how can tell Spring to throw my custom exception when catches `DataIntegrityViolationException`

Comment: With `throw` ?!

Comment: @Oleg , what i need is to make Spring handle it, whenever Spring catches  DataIntegrityViolationException, it should throw my custom exception .

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, `throw` whatever you want from your `handleConflict` method.

Comment: @Oleg, in Spring we don't  catch exception with try and catch, Spring framework has ControllerAdvice annotation feature which can catch some kind of exception, without developer code. now Spring Can catch DataIntegrityViolationException, what i need is when Spring catches DataIntegrityViolationException i want Spring to throw and  and handle another (my exception)  exception.

Comment: You don't need to catch you need to `throw`

Comment: @Oleg, i don't need catch and i don't  need throw, what i need is whenever  Spring Framework  detect DataIntegrityViolationException, handle it using my generic handler which handles a different type of exceptions.

Comment: Whatever, good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My sample code. this is commonExceptionHandler.
You use "Throw exception" your service and dao layer. spring handle your exception.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class, SQLException.class })
public @ResponseBody String checkDefaultException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception,
        HttpServletResponse resp) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CommonExceptionModel model = new CommonExceptionModel();

    model.setMessage("InternalServerError");
    model.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString());

    String commonExceptionString = mapper.writeValueAsString(model);

    logger.error(commonExceptionString + " exception : " + exception);

    return commonExceptionString;
}
```

Your error reference : [enter link description here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception)